# what Should be the SQL query for the below result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What should be the SQL query if we want a result in the form of **table 2** from **table 1**

**Table 1:**

```
Type1 | Type2
------|-------
A     |  Dev
B     |  User
C     |  User1
User  |  Dev
User1 |  User
User2 |  User1
```

**Table 2:**

```
X| Y
------|-------
A     |  Dev
B     |  User
B     |  Dev
C     |  User1
C     |  User
C     |  Dev
User  |  Dev
User1 |  User
User1 |  Dev
User2 |  User1
User2 |  User
User2 |  Dev
```

Comment: please explain your result

Comment: As You can see that in the 3rd Row, value of 1st column is C and the value of 2nd column is User1
But value of User1 according to 1st table is User
And value of User according to 1st table is Dev
So for the 3rd row we got the 3 Result.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Looks like a recursive self join is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below script, using a recursive CTE here.

```
DECLARE @TABLE  TABLE
(
    Type1   NVARCHAR(10)
    ,Type2  NVARCHAR(10)
)   
INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES ('A','Dev'),('B','User'),('C','User1'),('User','Dev'),('User1','User'),('User2','User1')

;WITH CTE
AS
(   SELECT  Type1,Type2
    FROM    @TABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  C.Type1, T.Type2
    FROM    CTE AS  C
        INNER JOIN  @TABLE  AS  T   ON  T.Type1 =   C.Type2
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY Type1,Type2 DESC
```

Output

```
Type1   Type2
A       Dev
B       User
B       Dev
C       User1
C       User
C       Dev
User    Dev
User1   User
User1   Dev
User2   User1
User2   User
User2   Dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abdul sir...

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.Type1 as X,
       t2.Type2 as Y
from table1 t1
join (select distinct Type2 from table1) t2
   on  t1.Type2 >= t2.Type2
order by x, y desc
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>select t1.Type1 as X,
SQL&       t2.Type2 as Y
SQL&from table1 t1
SQL&join (select distinct Type2 from table1) t2
SQL&   on  t1.Type2 >= t2.Type2
SQL&order by x, y desc;
X          Y
========== ==========
A          Dev
B          User
B          Dev
C          User1
C          User
C          Dev
User       Dev
User1      User
User1      Dev
User2      User1
User2      User
User2      Dev

                 12 rows found
```

Comment: I think they are looking for the hierarchy to be followed not just `t1.Type2 >= t2.Type2`. In their example data everyone is connected but it would be possible to come up with data where this isn't the case.

Comment: @MartinSmith, maybe you're right. No explanation at all, and perhaps poor sample data...